# After the Exodus was Egypt totally ruined or not?

Tags: history, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt

We had the 10 plagues, we had the Egyptians drowned in the sea, but what's the bottom-line - was Egypt at Egyptians totally ruined and the end of the story or despite the fact that some died, Egypt continued to exist normally?

This [part of the question] is purely historical/factual.

---

<sub>The afterthoughts for the perplexed: fighting the evil requires total extermination of it and its roots (see the story of Amalek - the war of Yehoshua or Shaul or Haman). So theoretically, fighting Egyptians (if the were The Evil) required the final solution. But on the other hand, if the Keter was exterminated there was no way of the other four Exiles. Puzzling...</sub>

Comment: "The Evil"???  Whatever that's supposed to mean, it's an explicit pasuk that they're not it! https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.8

Comment: Saul and David did not, to my knowledge, eradicate Philistines from the face of the planet, they merely fended off any attempts they had to invade the Holy Land. Neither did Moses exterminate Egyptians wholesale, but only those who attacked or pursued them, which ended up being drowned. In a certain sense, the Egyptians were indeed annihilated, inasmuch as none of those that went out of Egypt (and were influenced by their pagan customs) entered into the Promised Land.

Comment: @Heshy You are right, and that's exactly what the question is about - what kind of evil were they - were they intrinsically bad to be eradicated or a little bad - just punished but not more. Or maybe you're actually answering the question - if Hashem requires us to accept them they weren't so bad and they weren't totally ruined! Please post it and I'll accept it B"N.

Comment: @Heshy You're wrong, the pasuk does not say anything about their qualities, it just teaches us to be thankful for the first period, not for the last when they turned [so to say] evil.

Comment: @Heshy Anyway the body of the question asked about the Egyptian history in our sources - **how badly damaged was Egypt after the Exodus in our sources**.

Answer (score 2):

Its depends when you hold the story of yetzias mitzraim accured.

according to the scholars that it happened in the times of rammses then there are no records of egypts collapse after yetzias mitzraim.

but according to egyptologist david rohl (who brings back the date a few hundred years. this view is explained in a documenty called: patterns of evidence - the exodus) then right after yetzias mitzraim there was one of egypts "black periods" where other nations took control over egypt very easily.

Comment: Who told you he is a professor. I heard otherwise

Comment: +1, but could you please give a link to this paper

Answer (score 0):

No, Egypt was not totally in ruins. They continued to thrive for another thousand years. Rome eventually conquered them and they converted to Christianity, which in turn converted to Islam.

During the 6-Days'-War Israel defeated the dark forces of Egypt. I think there was an episode where Jewish fighter jets flew over Cairo. We could have annihilated them then. But Israel is a holy nation. We left them untouched. Though Egypt continuously bombarded cites like Tel Aviv. Egypt even aided the anti-semites palestinians [philistine] in all their dark endeavors.

G-d could if He Wills it, rain down a heavenly fire and torch Egypt to the ground as He had done with Sodom. But after the Sea came crashing down on pharaoh' chariots, the angels were singing. G-d silenced them, saying "My handiwork is drowning in the sea, and you want to sing?"[1]

"For your ways are not MY ways," says HaShem.

[1] See Talmud in Megila (10b) which relates this story.